# How to use the different styles (mainly color schemes) of minted (pygments)?

Tags: color, tcolorbox, minted

How can you use the different minted styles?. For example solarized-dark, monokai,...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{minted}
%\usemintedstyle{solarized-dark}

\begin{document}

\begin{minted}[style=solarized-dark]{python}
from typing import Iterator

# This is an example
class Math:
    @staticmethod
    def fib(n: int) -> Iterator[int]:
    """Fibonacci series up to n."""
    a, b = 0, 1
    while a < n:
        yield a
        a, b = b, a + b

result = sum(Math.fib(42))
print("The answer is {}".format(result))
\end{minted}

\end{document}
```

[image]

*Edited after mbert comment:*

A **rude solution** is put a color NAME in LaTeX (minted) in order to avoid a limmitation of minted (not CODE color for background, tes color NAME )

[image]

Comment: Look for `bgcolor` in the [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/minted/minted.pdf)

Comment: A solution is putting a color NAME to avoid the minted limitation in the color background (beacause pygments works fine): \definecolor{base03}{HTML}{002b36}

\begin{minted}[style=solarized-dark,bgcolor=base03]{python}